# Are "one" and "one's" used correctly in these two sentences?

Tags: pronouns, genderless-pronouns

Is the following paragraph correct in a formal English article? Or there is a better way to write it? My doubt is about *one* and *one's*. Are they used in the paragraph correctly?

Thanks

> One also can design one’s own strategy to show the advantages. This is useful, since one’s users are facing a new way of communication.

Comment: whose users? The one who designed (?) his or her strategy?

Answer (score 1):

Using *one* as a gender-neutral personal is not unheard of in English, but it can sound archaic at times.

It is used in the paragraph *grammatically*, but whether it is *idiomatic* is another matter.

I would say that using either *you* or *they* is more idiomatic these days:

> - You can also design your own strategy to show the advantages. This is useful, since your users are facing a new way of communication.
> - They can also design their own strategy to show the advantages. This is useful, since their users are facing a new way of communication.

Unfortunately, in English, there's no equivalent indefinite third-person pronoun other than *one*, which is rarely heard outside of formal period (or satirical) discourse.

In answer to your question: yes, it's correct. But it's a little unusual, and as mentioned, because it's vague in referent, it can be difficult to track the participant which *one* refers to.